# R glm() with a categorical response variable

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, glmm

I want to know whether I can use glm() with a categorical response variable, and if yes how exactly.
I have a response variable with three unordered levels, and both categorical and continuous predictors. Here is an example dataset with just continuous predictors:

```
outcome <- gl(3,1,20)
expl1 <- runif(20, min=0, max=100)
expl2 <- runif(20, min=0, max=100)

mod1 <- glm(formula = factor(outcome) ~ expl1 + expl2, family = binomial())
summary(mod1)
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  0.205746   1.412173   0.146    0.884
expl1       -0.001620   0.016636  -0.097    0.922
expl2        0.008509   0.014943   0.569    0.569
```

When I compare the output to that of MCMCglmm():

```
expl <- cbind(expl1, expl2)
x <- cbind(outcome, expl)  
x <- as.data.frame(x)

 IJ <- (1/3) * (diag(2) + matrix(1, 2, 2))
 prior = list(R = list(V = IJ, fix = 1))
 mod2 <- MCMCglmm(factor(outcome) ~ -1 + trait:(expl1 + expl2), rcov = ~us(trait):units,
              prior = prior, data = x, family = "categorical",
              verbose = FALSE)

 summary(mod2)
```

In MCMCglmm() I code with 'trait' to express the latent variables 2/3, and consequently the output has separate coefficients for level 2/3:

```
  Location effects: factor(outcome) ~ -1 + trait:(expl1 + expl2) 

                      post.mean  l-95% CI  u-95% CI eff.samp pMCMC
 traitoutcome.2:expl1 -0.006716 -0.036872  0.025785    80.26 0.690
 traitoutcome.3:expl1 -0.010447 -0.041454  0.017851   103.78 0.516
 traitoutcome.2:expl2  0.004231 -0.021471  0.037971    67.26 0.808
 traitoutcome.3:expl2  0.011534 -0.014867  0.041410   105.17 0.424
```

The glm() output does not feature this, so I am worried it is interpreting 'outcome' as a continuous variable despite my use of factor(). As far as I have found in glm() descriptions, defining dummy variables is not necessary (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797087/how-to-create-dummy-variables-for-use-in-a-glm-in-r). Also, the glm families does not include a multinominal model, and I'm not sure whether the binominal model (as I did above) can be used, despite glm() above not throwing an error. Any help is very welcome.

PS In reality, I need a mixed model, which supposedly can be fitted by glmmPQL() in the MASS library, which depends om glm(). Hence the question about glm() only. I want to compare results with MCMCglmm().

EDIT: OK my question was perhaps too long and not very clear. But it's not a duplicate. I don't want to know which function I can use for a multinomial regression. I want to know if glm() can do it. Or, how I can make it work with glmmPQL() as suggested elsewhere. Again, I need a mixed model and it's not clear from the suggested duplicate question that nnet's multinom() can deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

Logically, you want to use multinomial logistic regression; see, for example, function `multinom()` in the [**nnet**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=nnet) package.